# Failed to start service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - local.xconnect-IndexWorker

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework, installation

Hi I am trying to install Sitecore 9 using SIF and a PowerShell script provided with the ELearning Sitecore 9 developer foundations. I've had quite a few issue during this including getting Solr 6.6.2 setup. I seem to have over come these problems, however one that has stumped me over the last few day is this exception:

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Failed to start service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - local.xconnect-IndexWorker (local.xconnect-IndexWorker)'. At C:\sitecore\install\install.ps1:43 char:1 + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:02:50 Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - local.xconnect-IndexWorker (local.xconnect-IndexWorker)'. At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-ManageServiceTask.ps1:40 char:33 + $instance | Start-Service + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

So far I found some threads on here explaining how they fixed it and giving the error messages from the logs. I have tried a few things although they would appear to have this issue for different reason. For example a common cause of this seems to be that their license has expired or does not include xConnect. I don't believe this is my issue because I am using a license from a another Sitecore 9 project that uses xConnect that works.

Also the error message in my xConnect logs seems to be different to when this is the case:

```
2019-10-11 18:00:29.419 +01:00 [Information] Starting Xdb Indexer App Domain, Machine: LAPTOP-171, InstanceName: XConnectIndexer_AppDomain 
2019-10-11 18:00:30.223 +01:00 [Information] SystemPerformanceCounters Constructor, Instance:XConnectIndexer, Path: App_Data\Diagnostics, CounterFilePattern: *.json 
2019-10-11 18:00:31.376 +01:00 [Error] Exception occurred during instantiating of IndexerHost. System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed. 
    at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind) at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrCoreUri.ReplaceCoreName(String newCoreName) at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriterSettings..ctor(SolrCoreUri coreUri, Int32 maximumUpdateBatchSize, Int32 maximumDeleteBatchSize, Int32 maximumCommitMilliseconds, Int32 parallelizationDegree, Int32 retryCount, Int32 maximumRetryDelayMilliseconds, Encoding encoding, IndexerSettings indexerSettings) at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.RebuildSolrWriterSettings..ctor(String rebuildCoreName, SolrWriterSettings solrWriterSettings, Uri rebuildCoreWriteUrl, Uri rebuildCoreCleanUri, Uri rebuildCoreStatusPath, Uri swapCoresUri, Uri coreAdminUrl, Uri rebuildCoreCommitUrl) 
    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.RebuildSolrWriterSettings..ctor(SolrWriterSettings settings, String rebuildCoreName) 
    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrIndexRebuilder.GetRebuildSolrWriterSettings(SolrWriterSettings settings) 
    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrIndexRebuilder..ctor(SolrWriterSettings writerSettings, XdbModel xdbModel) 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationServiceType.c__DisplayClass24_0.b__0(IServiceProvider sp) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationServiceType.c__DisplayClass24_0.b__0(IServiceProvider sp) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider) 
    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerHost..ctor(IConfigurationRoot config) in C:\BA\147b0adf6c2580c7\code\Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer\IndexerHost.cs:line 46 
    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.IndexerHostAppDomainBridge..ctor() in C:\BA\147b0adf6c2580c7\code\Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer\IndexerAppDomainHost.cs:line 149
```

I did find a blog post mentioning the error here https://tothecore.sk/2018/08/09/sitecore-xconnect-search-indexer-windows-service-throwing-exception-the-authority-host-could-not-be-parsed/

But I'm not sure really what his fix is. When I try to run the script with the URL he suggests it then can't establish a connection with SOLR.

I also can't start the server manually through the server manager. I get the same error in the Window event logs.

Below is the script I'm running from the sitecore 9 set up guide.

```
#define parameters 
$prefix = "local" 
$PSScriptRoot = "C:\sitecore\install" 
$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix.sc" 
$SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8983/solr/#" 
$SolrRoot = "C:\sitecore\install\Solr-6.6.2" 
$SolrService = "Solr-6.6.2" 
$SqlServer = "(local)" 
$SqlAdminUser = "sa" 
$SqlAdminPassword="kagoolpass01" 
#install client certificate for xconnect 
$certParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"     
    CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client" 
}  
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose 

#install solr cores for xdb 
$solrParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 

#deploy xconnect instance 
$xconnectParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"     
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix     
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl      
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams 

#install solr cores for sitecore 
$solrParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 

#install sitecore instance 
$xconnectHostName = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreParams = @{    
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-XP0.json"      
    `enter code here`Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 
    (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip" 
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix  
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    Sitename = $sitecoreSiteName         
    XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectCollectionService"    
}

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
```

Just wondering if anyone out there might have any insight into why this could be happening.

Comment: Normally, the service has already been installed. So, from the services, can you start the XConnect Service manually? Also, you need to make sure that Solr is running under https

Comment: Hi Hishaam, No I can't when I attempt to start manually I get 'Error 1064: An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request'. The Windows event logs state the same thing. When I try to start it through cmd I get the same error as stated previously.

Comment: Hi @Shaun1810, Which version of Sitecore 9? I had faced few hiccups during Sitecore installation with SIF. For Sitecore 9 initial release, the SIF Framework to use would 1.2 and for Sitecore 9.1 and above, it is recommended to use SIF 2 and above.

Comment: Hi I was using 2.0, it is site core 9.0. I've switched to 1.2 and it's still the same issue.  It doesn't want to start manually either. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the editing and for the comments. It looks like the issue was with my SOLR url in the script. That extra /# on the SOLR address seemed to break the url it was generating for the xconnect connection string.

So instead of https://localhost:8983/solr/# it should be https://localhost:8983/solr. Looks like the post I read was correct(https://tothecore.sk/2018/08/09/sitecore-xconnect-search-indexer-windows-service-throwing-exception-the-authority-host-could-not-be-parsed/). It's annoying I've been stuck for a few days for something that simple. I am new Sitecore though.The guide actually isn't very clear about this. It has it with a slash at the end. And someone who is a beginner at the stage the tutorial is aimed at wouldn't necessarily see anything wrong with it.

Thanks again.

Comment: If you are still having installation issues, I would recommend you to follow the installation steps mentioned here: https://buoctrenmay.com/2018/11/29/sitecore-xp-9-1-step-by-step-install-guide-on-your-machine/ The steps given here are clear and easy to replicate. I have used this link personally for installing Sitecore on my instance.